# LoopBack: "order" filter not always applied

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a model that uses the memory connector. On the client side the REST-API request looks like this:

```
TrackedAircraft.find({ filter:
    { order: 'altitude ASC',
      where: { altitude: { neq: null }}
    }
}).$promise.then(function (results) {
      $scope.aircrafts = results;
});
```

"altitude" is a numeric value. Most of the time this works as expected, but like 1% of the requests end up with the default order.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere? I want to confirm the bug by reproducing it before filing an issue.

Comment: I dug around a bit and found out that the sorting get's messed up when  values are undefined. JS always returns false when comparing to undefined. Already filed a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your db queries in console, starting the app as

`DEBUG=loopback:datasource slc run`.

Add if queries will be correct, but response - not, dig deeper to db's result handler.

Comment: I tried getting debug output, but the memory connector doesn't seem to produce any output.

Comment: I think you should explore how filtering works.
Try do debug `Memory.prototype.all` in node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/connectors/memory.js.